# When were the decrees against the boys made?

Tags: sources-mekorot, time, parashas-shemos

In Parshat Sh'mot (Ex 1:15) Par'oh decrees that the boy children of the Hebrews should be killed.

When was that moment in relation to the timeline of events in Egypt (the death of Yosef, the appointing of taskmasters...)?

Par'oh then, seeing as this plan failed because, as reported by Shifra and Pu'ah (Yocheved and Miriam -- Rashi, 1:15, referencing Sotah 11b), the women give birth with no help, then decrees that every son (even the Egyptians, as per Rashi 1:22) born *on a certain day* would be thrown into the river. So would the decrees would cease after that moment? How long after the first decree was this day?

Miriam (age 6, and a midwife?) encourages her parents to have another child (Rashi 2:1 from Sotah 12a) after the second decree, and that child is Moshe. [though this conception and the timeline seem contested as per [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13311/when-was-moshe-conceived) question]

How long after the first decree was any of this? Was Aharon born between the decrees (he is 3 years older than Moshe) or before them completely?

I would think he was born before them completely because if he was born after the decree given to the Hebrew midwives (1:15) his mother would have been her own midwife (his sister was 3 when he was born) Par'oh would not have been telling THEM to kill the children. But if the decrees began after Aharon's birth, when his mother was back at work, that would make the duration of the decrees from after Aharon is born until the birth of Moshe, under 3 years, during which Yocheved would have been visibly pregnant for some months.

tl;dr

Is there a discussion of and a precise timeline extant of the events in Egypt which explains when each birth, conversation and decree in Sh'mot happened?